# Angular 2 function calls on double click

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, for-loop

I am creating pdf from json data using jsPDF

```
    responseStatus:any= [];

   pdfDownload(){
   this._isuGeoSubunitReportService.SubmitISUGEO(this.isugeosubunitTO)
    .subscribe(data =>this.responseStatus = data,
        err => console.log(err),
       () => console.log('Request Completed222')
);
var header = [];
var data = [];
var totalData = [];

var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
   doc.cellInitialize(); 
   doc.setFontSize(10); 

var count = 0;
for(let isugeo of this.responseStatus.dynaModel){
  count++;
  for(let isugeomap of this.generateArray(isugeo.map)){ 
     if(count==1){
     header.push(isugeomap.key); 
     } 
  }
}

 for(let isugeo of this.responseStatus.dynaModel){
   let temp = [];
  for(let isugeomap of this.generateArray(isugeo.map)){ 
     temp.push(isugeomap.value);     
  }
    data.push(temp);
}



 console.log('Request Completed2......22'+ JSON.stringify(data));
doc.autoTable(header,data,{
margin: {horizontal:1,top:1},
styles: {overflow: 'linebreak',theme: 'grid' },columnStyles: {
0: {columnHeight: 5}
}});
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

}

I am calling this fuction via a html button click

```
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isugeoForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-
  primary"  (click)="pdfDownload()">Export pdf</button>
```

now the problem is that when I hit the click button first time data is not come out from subscribe block, and give error in first 'for' loop that data length is zero. After second hit on button data shows.

why it wants two click for generation of correct pdf each time.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't "want two clicks" to generate your PDF : I'll explain it to you.

First, you create your variable :

```
responseStatus:any= [];
```

There's nothing in it. Then, you make your HTTP call on the click :

```
this._isuGeoSubunitReportService
  .SubmitISUGEO(this.isugeosubunitTO)
    .subscribe(data => this.responseStatus = data,
        err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Request Completed222')
    );
```

Now you have to understand, this is an **asynchronous call**. This means, it will make the call, but the code will keep going ! And once the response is there, it will process what is inside the subscribe.

This means that your code after that, which is

```
var header = [];
var data = [];
var totalData = [];
// ...
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Will be launched **while you're still waiting for the response**.

If you want to wait for the response, you have to move all of this code **into the subscribe**, or **into a function that is called into the subscribe**.

Otherwise, you will have to "make 2 clicks" !

Comment: nice explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are making an AJAX call which is synchronous and the 'for' loop runs
before it is successfully completed so `this.responseStatus.dynaModel` is `undefined`.You need
to execute the `for` loop after data has arrived, like this:

```
pdfDownload(){
    this._isuGeoSubunitReportService.SubmitISUGEO(this.isugeosubunitTO)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.responseStatus = data;
            this.generatePDF();
        },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Request Completed222')
        );
}

generatePDF() {
    var header = [];
    var data = [];
    var totalData = [];

    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    doc.cellInitialize();
    doc.setFontSize(10);

    var count = 0;
    for (let isugeo of this.responseStatus.dynaModel) {
        count++;
        for (let isugeomap of this.generateArray(isugeo.map)) {
            if (count == 1) {
                header.push(isugeomap.key);
            }
        }
    }

    for (let isugeo of this.responseStatus.dynaModel) {
        let temp = [];
        for (let isugeomap of this.generateArray(isugeo.map)) {
            temp.push(isugeomap.value);
        }
        data.push(temp);
    }

    console.log('Request Completed2......22' + JSON.stringify(data));
    doc.autoTable(header, data, {
        margin: { horizontal: 1, top: 1 },
        styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', theme: 'grid' }, columnStyles: {
            0: { columnHeight: 5 }
        }
    });
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
```